# Using Recyclerview and Cardview WITHOUT Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and have a large number of apps that do not use `Gradle`.

I would like to start using the `RecycleView` and `Cardview`.

What is the best way to add these? I have added in the two modules in a similar way to `AppCompat`.

However, when I try to run the code and show the `RecycleView`, I get this error...

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class RecyclerView
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the layout where you did declare the RecyclerView

Answer (score 3):

**Since you wanted it to wotk without adding them in gradle dependency**
navigate to your sdk location from that `sdk folder-->extras-->android-->support-->v7`

under this you will find recyclerview and cardview folders add them as library pojects respectively and you can proceed normally. THis can be done in eclipse also

Answer (score 0):

Your xml probably looks a bit like this:

```
<Recyclerview....
```

It needs to look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView....
```

Sorry if the formatting is off, posting from my phone!